# How to move image horizontal on screen automatically using timer?

Tags: java, android

I want to move the image(image ball) horizontally using Timer. I  try to move the ball horizontally. it moves sometime 2 or 3 times and then the app crashes.I want to move it on an infinite loop. Is there any perfect solution for automatically animate the image horizontally with time.?
thanks in advance.

```
    imageball = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_ball);
    imageball.setTranslationX(-500);
     timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void run() {

                                      imageball.setTranslationX(-500);

                                    imageball.animate().translationXBy(1500f).setDuration(5000);
                                      imageball.setAlpha(1f);
                                  }

                              },
            0, 7000);
```

Xml Code Here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_ball"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/greenball" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [`ObjectAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator) would serve your need.

You can set the **interval** between every animation by using `setStartDelay()` and you can set `repeatCount` to `ObjectAnimator.INFINITE` to make it run in **infinite loop**

Other kind of animations - https://developer.android.com/training/animation/overview

Hope it helps.